# Exporting data from QFieldCloud to external server

Tags: server, qfield-cloud

Is it possible to export directly data from QFieldCloud into an external server?

We are planning to set a server aiming to centralise wildlife census data collected with different apps, which one of them must be QField. Ideally, QField would feed the server directly, with no need of uploading the layers manually.

Many thanks!